# How to pass Base64String from File Upload to image property in FormGroup using PatchValue in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to convert an uploaded image will to a base64 string and sent to an API. I am using reactive form. The issue is that I keep having an error when patching the base64 string result to the FormGroup image property. Below is the code:

```
 onFileChange(event) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
     
      if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
        const [file] = event.target.files;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.formGroup.patchValue({
            file: reader.result as string
          });
        };
      }
    }
```

I keep getting trying to patch value to the form group, this error:

> ERROR DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Answer (score 0):

Make your onload method async and remove 'as string':

```
reader.onload = async () => {
   this.formGroup.patchValue({
      file: reader.result
   });
};
```

If for some reason that fails, asign the reader.result value to a var before using it:

```
let imgFile = reader.result; 
reader.onload = async () => {
   this.formGroup.patchValue({
      file: imgFile 
   });
}
```

Also, be sure to do `this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity()` after patching a value.

Comment: Thank you but it did not work, the problem seem to be with FormGroup patchValue  because when I used Template Form and use ngModel to bind, it work

Comment: You can always try this.formGroup.get('file').patchValue(imgFile). Do you have a working example on stackblitz or somewhere?